# How to insert specific amount of space between listbox item in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, space

How can I place listbox item separated from each other or leaving some space in between.

Answer (score 2):

I believe if you have a datatemplate, you can just add the following code to the listbox itself:  Margin="10"  (or any number you like) and that will set a space between each item.

Comment: For the record, the recommended margin is 12 on each side (so 24 between each item). In general, for consistent layout, make sure to use 12, 24, and 48 for margins.

Comment: You can set negative value for margin if you want decrease space between rows

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a template for the listbox items? Are you using databinding and the DataContext or ItemSource properties? I'm sure you can add margins to the items you add to the template to create the space you desire. Check out [Nerd Dinner Example](http://chriskoenig.net/2010/04/21/wp7-part-2-working-with-data/) for use of a template.